# C# Application and an SQL Server hosted online

Tags: c#, sql-server

If I have a C# application and a SQL Server database hosted at somee.com. Can I just get the connection string of the SQL Server database hosted at somee.com and put it in the AppConfig of my C# application?

Comment: Should able to, if the server allows remote connections. Did you try it?

Comment: Ask the support staff at sommee.com - if you're hosting there, the should be able to tell you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a database hosting plan you can connect to that database remotely. Open your “*User menu*”  and navigate to "*User -> Managed products -> MS SQL -> Databases -> (Database name)*" (or the option name they currently use). There you will find the connection string for your application and for MS SQL Management Studio as well.